# When rendering my partial view it is not set it an instance of an object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am attempting to use partial views for the first time and I need some help. I am posting a string from Javascript to my ASP controller so that I can query my database using that string. Like so:

**JavaScript**

```
function findEmployees(userCounty) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")',
        data: JSON.stringify(userCounty),
        contentType: "application/json",
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e)
            console.log("error")
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody]string userCounty)
    {
        string county = userCounty.Substring(0, userCounty.IndexOf(" "));
        var query = from SOP in _context.SalesOffice_Plant
                    where SOP.County == county
                    select new SalesOffice_Plant
                    {
                        Employee = SOP.Employee
                    };

        return PartialView(query.ToList());
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Contact Us";
        ViewBag.Current = "Contact";

        return View();
    }
```

When I set break points - I can see that the string is passed correctly and my LINQ query works just fine. My problem occurs when I want to render a table of the employees in my Index page. The JavaScript returns a value to the controller after the page loads. This means I needed a way to "refresh the page". I was told to use a partial view to solve this problem and this is what I came up with.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.SalesOffice_Plant>
//A bunch of Html
@await Html.PartialAsync("_IndexPartial")
//More Html
```

**_IndexPartial.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.SalesOffice_Plant>
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Ideally, I would like a table of Employees to be generated and displayed in the Index.cshtml. However, when I load the page I get and error telling me that my @await Html.PartialAsync("_IndexPartial") 'is not set to an instance of an object.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: When the file extension is present, the HTML Helper references a partial view that must be in the same folder as the markup file calling the partial view. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I combed through that post and I don't it answers my question. Also my Index.cshtml and _IndexPartial.cshtml are both in the same view folder called "Contact"

Comment: the contollection action `Index` which is marked as `HttpGet` does not pass any model value to its View `Index`. `Index` View renders the partial view `_IndexPartial` which tries to use the same model. Since the model to `Index` is null, the same is passed to the partial view which is causing the exception. You should replace `return View();` with `return View(new List<SalesOffice_Plant>());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use ajax,it would not reload your page after backend code finishing,so you need to use `.html()` method to render the backend result to html.

Here is a whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class SalesOffice_Plant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
<button type="button" onclick="findEmployees('a  ')">Find</button>
<div id="employee">      
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    function findEmployees(userCounty) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Contact")',
            data: JSON.stringify(userCounty),
            contentType: "application/json",
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e)
                console.log("error")
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $("#employee").html(res);    //add this...
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
}
```

Partial View(_IndexPartial.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<SalesOffice_Plant>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([FromBody] string userCounty)
{
    string county = userCounty.Substring(0, userCounty.IndexOf(" "));
    var query = from SOP in _context.SalesOffice_Plant
                where SOP.County == county
                select new SalesOffice_Plant
                {
                    Employee = SOP.Employee
                };
    return PartialView("_IndexPartial", query.ToList());  //must specify the partial view name
                                                          //otherwise it will match the action name as partial view name
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contact Us";
    ViewBag.Current = "Contact";
    return View();
}
```

Result:

[image]